# Add option to flag "useless" answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, flags

It would be nice to flag "useless" answers, those that aren't really spam, but still are junk.

For example see the OP's post on:

[How to install/enable ftpcopy binary and mysqldump binary on WHM cPanel](https://serverfault.com/questions/75499/how-to-install-enable-ftpcopy-binary-and-mysqldump-binary-on-whm-cpanel)

If it's been removed the OP left an answer of just:

> can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Feature Request: Ability to flag an answer as "not an answer" or "should be a comment"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40906/feature-request-ability-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer-or-should-be-a-com)

Comment: @Andrew Grimm, please look at the dates, this question is almost 6 months older than the one you are pointing to. So if there is a duplicate, this question isn't the one.

Comment: @Gamecat: Strange - I thought it didn't allow using a newer one as a duplicate. Anyway, the other one seems better answered.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Click the flag link and you'll see these among the options:

> #### not an answer
>
> This was posted as an answer, but it does not answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.
>
> #### very low quality
>
> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

You'll probably be using the first option most of the time.

Answer (score 5):

Down vote them.

Comment: Doesn't help most of the time. For many people, it's their last post and they'll never log in.

Comment: @Mehrdad-If the user is so touchy, the can't handle the downvote, how long are they going to last on SO with all the disagreements, downvoting, and closing of questions?  Personally, I think this is exactly what downvoting was meant for, isn't it?

Comment: John: You misunderstood my point. I meant many users that post those "Thanks" and "can anyone help" posts are newbies who ask a single question and they might never come back to see the downvote and delete the post. Adding a comment can be useful for users who come back to understand SO is not phpBB but doesn't help removing the clutter most of the time.

Comment: But it makes the answer drop to the bottom, where it won't necessarily be seen.

Comment: @RobS: that is a good thing

Comment: Yes, but we'll wind up with lots of garbage at the bottom of every post. Having the lower quality answers at the bottom is fine, but garbage is just a waste.